# What are the parts of a Window called in MS Windows?

Tags: windows, terminology

A Window in MS Windows is composed of a title bar, toolbars, etc.

What is the main area of a window called, though?

What if there is more than one area (such as in the Windows Explorer, where there is a tree to the left and directory content to the right)? Is there a common name for this? Panes? Subwindows?

Is there unified terminology across OSes and window managers, or does each WM have their own vocabulary?

Comment: Nobody is in charge of a "unified terminology", so therefore there ain't one. :) Some terms, like "controls" tend to have common meaning, but those are usually concepts and not implementations. 

There are two levels of terminology: the conceptual level or what the "users" (or interface designers) would call the pieces, and what the actual API calls them. (Sometimes these are the same.)  All I can tell you re: the Win shell is that traditionally each control with screen real estate is backed by an HWND, meaning they're all "windows".

Comment: Sounds like an answer quixoto!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632597%28VS.85%29.aspx